# How to compile qtminer on linux?

Tags: mining, cpp-ethereum, compilation, miner, qtminer

Etherchain provides the source code of the [qtminer on github](https://github.com/etherchain-org/qtminer). However, no build instructions and no build helpers are provided.

Does anyone have any idea how to compile qtminer on linux? What are the dependencies? It looks like you need to embedd it somehow in the whole cpp-ethereum suite.

Is it still possible to build it myself? The binaries on the net are windows only.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Makefile below. You may have to adjust your paths to reach your webthree-umbrella build targets, but this should get you started.

```
# MAKEFILE for QTMiner.
# Very simple makefile to get it to build the qtminer executable

CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
INCLUDES = -I/usr/local/include
LFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib
LIBS = -lethashseal -lethereum

all: qtminer

qtminer:  qtminer.o main.o
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o qtminer qtminer.o main.o $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

qtminer.o:  qtminer.cpp qtminer.h 
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c qtminer.cpp

main.o:  main.c
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c

clean: 
  $(RM) count *.o *~
```

Comment: `fatal error: libethcore/EthashGPUMiner.h: file not found`